# О каких "мышках" речь?

Tags: этимология

И еще один вопрос из анатомии))) Почему место под рукой называется "подмышка"? О какой "мышке" тут речь и при чем она тут вообще?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

О мышще. Раньше мышцы называли "мышки" (также как и в латинское musculus от мыши), что до сих пор заметно при словообразовании (спазм мышечный, а не мышцевый). Так что "подмышка=подмышца", что вполне объясняется её местонахождением под мышцами.